# I am trying to open a file that is a json. and store it as an json object.

Tags: c++, json

I am trying to open a file that has a json extension and store it as an object.  However,  keep getting an error message that the file name was not declared in the scope.  I'm new to working with json files.  do you treat them differently than normal text files?

```
#include "json.hpp"
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

std::ifstream file;
file.open(test.json);
nlohmann::json jsonObject;
// Store the contents filename into jsonObject
if (file.is_open()) {
  file >> jsonObject;

}
file.close();

}
```

Comment: `file.open("test.json")`

Comment: "... file name was not declared in the scope." Has nothing *at all* to do with the file being json (or whatever else). Btw; please *always* post any compiler errors you get *verbatim*.

Comment: Please also trim your code to a minimal example, as it stands, it is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You pass `test.json` as filename to the `open`-function. Thereby the compiler assumes an object named `test` with a data member `json`. Unless you have such an object defined in your code, compiler will tell you that there is no object named `test` in the scope. That's why.

You probably meant...

```
if (file.open("test.json")) {
   ...
```